# jQuery Click Not Being Called in bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a huge issue with an item in the navbar not being able to use the click()

this is my html code:

```
 <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="n-btn" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="icon-bullhorn"></i> <span class="badge badge-inverse" id="n-count" style="position: relative; bottom: 2px;">1</span> </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu alert-dropdown">
        <ul>
        <li class="text-center"><span class="pulser"></span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
```

and my javascript:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#n-btn").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

I tried using `$(".dropdown").on("click", "#n-btn",function() {` instead but it still doesn't work. If this changes anything I'm using jquery 2.0.0 and Bootstrap 2.3.2

Comment: Why not use `DOM Ready` instead of load.. How abt the browser you are trying on ?

Comment: Any error messages in your console?  I tested in jsfiddle and your alert fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [Bootstrap source for 2.3.2](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v2.3.2/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js#L31) it looks like it triggers the `click.dropdown.data-api` event, so instead of:

```
$("#n-btn").click(function(e) {
```

use (for Bootstrap 2.x):

```
$("#n-btn").on('click.dropdown.data-api', function(e) { ...
```

For Bootstrap 3.x (looking at its version of [dropdown.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.5/js/dropdown.js#L19)), try:

```
$("#n-btn").on('click.bs.dropdown', function(e) { ...
```

Comment: The event type is still `click`. The rest is a [namespace](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names).